How to create routes with FastAPI within a class and classy-fastapi - followup
I am using classy_fastapi for a while now but noticed that routes are not carried over in sub classes? is that expected behaviour ?
i.e.
class A(Routable):
 def __init__():
    super().__init__()

   @get('/user')
   def get_user():
      return "some user"

class B(A):
   def __init__():
    super().__init__()

  @get('/company')
  def get_company():
      return "company"

The instance of class B won't know about route '/user'.
Any ideas?
Expecting that routes are available in instances of sub class.

although i do not use inheritance that much (since it is messy using the super().__init__() method, i like this question.

not that it hugely matters, but why do you use 1, 3 and 4 spaces for indentation ?  (the norm is 4).

Because i was in a rush ...

You would have to inherit the method(s) from class A for making the routes available.
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    # Inheriting the route from parent
    get_user = A.get_user

    @get('/company')
    def get_company(self):
        return "company"


Thank you for your consideration, it does actually do the job. I thought it might be the routes that need to be redeclared, but its the first time I see it expressed this way. Thanks  (alas - never stop learning ).
Is this something specific to Routable?

Routes are not inheritable because the current implementation of Routable uses a metaclass that inspects class members by calling the values method of the members dict, which does not include members of any parent class:
class RoutableMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls: Type[type], name: str, bases: Tuple[Type[Any]], attrs: Dict[str, Any]) -> 'RoutableMeta':
        endpoints: List[EndpointDefinition] = []
        for v in attrs.values(): # <- this does not include members of parents
            if inspect.isfunction(v) and hasattr(v, '_endpoint'):
                endpoints.append(v._endpoint)
        attrs['_endpoints'] = endpoints
        return cast(RoutableMeta, type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs))

You can make routes inheritable by redefining Routable yourself with an __init_subclass__ method that initializes a subclass after it has been instantiated so that within the method it can use dir(cls) to obtain members of both the subclass and its base classes:
import inspect
from functools import partial
from classy_fastapi import Routable

class Routable:
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls._endpoints = [
            obj._endpoint for obj in map(partial(getattr, cls), dir(cls))
            if inspect.isfunction(obj) and hasattr(obj, '_endpoint')
        ]

    __init__ = Routable.__init__

so that:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from classy_fastapi import get

class A(Routable):
    @get('/user')
    def get_user(self):
        return "some user"

class B(A):
    pass
    
app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(B().router)
client = TestClient(app)
response = client.get('/user')
print(response.text)

will output:
"some user"

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/StingyAthleticKeygens
Note that I've also submitted a merge request to the author of classy_fastapi so that this feature can be made official.

Thank you for the clarification,  very much appreciated. Also noting that I don't seem the only one who stumbled over this.

You're welcome. My answer was not meant to be just a clarification, but also a solution. I've updated the answer with a demo code so you can try it out yourself.

indeed it is also a solution, however it came after  Vishal Jaiswar which i accepted.

Vishal's answer does not actually make the subclass inherit any method, despite its claim. It is an explicit assignment for every route in the base class, violating the DRY principle. Note that you are free to accept a different answer by clicking on the grey check mark at any time.
